# Location of logs for java.util.logger

Tags: java, sql, jsp, logging, informix

I am on windows, and using squirrel client to access a database on informix.
On my jsp pages there are code that open the databse informix for query.

Other than out printing the error message on the webpage where the code is eg: the code is in file DB123.jsp, then the error message can be printed out at //100.100.100.100/DB123.jsp on browser.

My question is if I have a `java.sql.SQLException`, where else can I look at more **detailed error message**, or what configuration should I make to have it enabled? Because sometimes sql error unable to be printed on the webpage.

The code at DB123.jsp with the log:

```
public Logger myLog = Logger.getLogger("DB123.jsp");

{...}
catch(SQLException sqle){
        strMsg = "failed";
        strMsgDesc = ERR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE+sqle; 　//this one out print on webpage
        myLog.error(sqle.getMessage()); 　//This line i dont know where it logs to
}...

array.put("msgdesc", strMsgDesc);
out.print(array);
/***end****/
```

If there is a syntax error on sql statement, the flow of the program should stopped at `sql.executeQuery();` right? So the logging of error should be on the dev environment server, there wont be any thing to be debug at informix server right? So IBM interactive debugger would not help here.

Whenever I google 'location of logs of java.util.logging' or a similar phrase, I could not get any good explanation. Many searches returns codes of how to setup the logger, but not where the logs are.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to print the various parts of the `SQLException`?
The Informix JDBC documentation mentions the methods `getMessage()`, `getErrorCode()` and `getSQLState()`.
It also mentions that you can get the syntax errors offset.

Comment: The [java.util.logging API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) doesn't have an `error` method. Your example has `myLog.error(sqle.getMessage());` which means that the logger is not a `java.util.logger`